# Conversion of Microsoft Access files

Tags: ms-access

I have a master file that was corrupted when changing from 97 to 07. Now, all I have is a replica of the original master file, and I cannot change it back into the master so more users can access it. How can I convert it to a master file in 07? (I have tried using Microsoft's file they gave to help convert, but it only opens in 97)

Comment: Is it possible that this question should be asked on superuser.com It doesn't seem as though it's a development question.

Comment: Wild guess: *Save As...* and pick a file type at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Except for tedious manual work, this may be your only chance:

[TSI Access 2000 Un-Replicator, a ComAddIn](http://trigeminal.fmsinc.com/lang/1033/utility.asp?ItemID=7#7)